# sql filter only if parameter is not 0

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

Hello I have the following procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE searchMembers(IN param1 INT, IN param2 INT, IN age INT)
  searchMembers:BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM members
      WHERE param1=param1 
      AND param2=param2
      AND age=age;
    END;
```

But I want each filter to exist only if params are not equal to zero. For example, if I run `CALL searchMembers(12, 24, 0);` the executed query should be

```
    SELECT * FROM members
      WHERE param1=param1 
      AND param2=param2;
    END;
```

Any ideas how to do that?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: `where (c1 = p1 or p1 is null) and (...`

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using?  "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. And the syntax for stored procedures and parameter handling is highly product specific

Comment: @GordonLinoff looks like oracle

Answer (score 1):

First, name your parameters so they do not conflict with column names.

Then, I would expect something like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE searchMembers (
    IN in_param1 INT,
    IN in_param2 INT,
    IN in_age INT
) AS
BEGIN
    SELECT m.*
    FROM members m
    WHERE (m.param1 = in_param1 OR in_param1 IS NULL) AND
          (m.param2 = in_param2 OR in_param2 IS NULL) AND
          (m.age = in_age OR in_age IS NULL);
END;
```

Note that this uses `NULL` to denote *all*.  This is a much more typical choice, but you can use similar logic for `0` if that is what you really want.

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM members
 WHERE (param1 = 0 or col1 = param1)
   AND (param2 = 0 or col2 = param2)
   AND (age_param = 0 or age = age_param)
```